# java.io.FileNotFoundException only occurs when run inside AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an odd problem; if I run this code I get a java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=1234&access_token=1234. This only occurs when I call `client.getInputStream()` inside my `AsyncTask`. Click the link: it clearly works.
Let's call this case 1.

Now, when I run the exact same code outside of my `AsyncTask`, I get a NetworkOnMainThreadException, but `client.getInputStream()` works...
Consider this case 2.

I know why I get the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` in case 2, but I don't understand why the `FileNotFoundException` only happens in case 1, and not in case 2. The code is identical! I've been looking at this for hours and I just don't know what I am doing wrong.

EDIT: apperently the `FileNotFoundException` occurs because of an error response code. I figured this out by getting the error stream with `.getErrorStream()` when the exception occurs.

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Temp {

    private String getResponse(InputStream stream){
        Scanner s = new Scanner(stream).useDelimiter("\\A");
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
    }

    public void run(String url){
        URL uri;
        HttpsURLConnection client = null;
        try {
            uri = new URL(url);
            client = (HttpsURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
            client.setReadTimeout(15*1000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new RetrieveStream().execute(client);
    }

    private class RetrieveStream extends AsyncTask<HttpsURLConnection, Void, String> {
        private String returnString = null; //don't change this!
        HttpsURLConnection client;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(HttpsURLConnection... client) {
            try {
                this.client = client[0];
                InputStream stream = this.client.getInputStream();
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "response: "+getResponse(this.client.getInputStream()));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "error output: "+getResponse(this.client.getErrorStream()));
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "error: "+getResponse(this.client.getErrorStream()));
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            this.client.disconnect();
            return returnString;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String output) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "output: "+output);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit strange that you're opening the connection, and then passing that into the `AsyncTask`. Have you tried just passing the `URL` into the `AsyncTask`, and then doing all of the initialization inside `doInBackground()` instead?

Comment: @NoChinDeluxe It only aprears strange; this is a bare minumum example of my actual class, which has methods to set headers, request method, etcetera etcetara. All this happens outside of the `AsyncTask` ofcourse. But this bare minimal example still doesn't work.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not this is the real code or an example, it's weird that you initialize the connection OUTSIDE of the background thread and then pass an open connection into another thread. That is what is strange and I'm betting that's the issue. I would try doing all of your connection init, including headers and everything else, inside of `doInBackground()`.

Comment: It might be weird to you. To me it makes perfect sense. It makes no difference if I initialise the `HttpsUrlConnection` outside the `AsyncTask` and pass it to `doInBackground` or if I pass a `URL` and initialise inside the `AsyncTask`. It shouldn't, since this isn't a static class. If it were a static class, you might be onto something. And I tried, and I still get the same error ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear why the `FileNotFoundException` occurs, but I was able to get the response with `.getErrorStream()` instead of `.getInputStream()`. My question is edited accordingly. Please ignore the other answers, they provide no solutions.

Answer (score 0):

i am not deep into android development, but since the Thread seem to be aware of connections (implied by "NetworkOnMainThreadException"), i'd suggest to handover the URL instance to your AsyncTask and open the connection there, instead of hand over the client.

Apart from this, by reading the api, i'd expect a

```
client.connect();
```

before

```
client.getInputStream();
```

get's called.

References:

https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#openConnection()
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream()

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. My class uses `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`, which is different. To be sure, I tried it with a `client.connect()`, still the same error. Handing over the URL instance also doesn't fix anything.

Comment: `.connect` is not required with java.net.HttpUrlConnection https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html, which explains why it doens't solve anything...